# Why doesn't twitter search return results?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, twitter

I have a jQuery plugin on a site I maintain. It fetches json results from the twitter api. However, since yesterday there are no results coming from the server anymore. Also, on twitter itself I'm not getting the expected results ether. Why does http://twitter.com/#!/search/from%3Ajasperkennis return results, while http://twitter.com/#!/search/realtime/from%3Ansma_ doesn't?

Comment: is the user : `nsma_` correctly spell?

Comment: Yep: http://twitter.com/#!/nsma_

Comment: Are they both users? The second doesn't look like a user name or belongs to a see who perhaps hasn't tweeted. Also the second query is real time where the first is not.

Comment: As you could have seen for yourself, yes, they are both users. And the 'realtime' part is added by twitter. If you go to the url without the 'realtime' part in the url it will be added automatically.

Comment: Why is this off topic? This IS a practical problem answerable, and at the time I posted it for me it was highly likely that the answer would be related to programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twitter is a large website with billions of tweets each week. There's absolutely no way to make a billion tweets searchable, so Twitter only picks a certain group of tweets (the interesting and non-spammy ones) and lets those turn up in the search indexes only.

If you want all tweets from a certain user, use the `statuses/user_timeline` API method, not the search API.

http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=nsma_

Comment: Did they change the criteria for selecting tweets to return than? 'Cause a lot more results were returned before, only since three days the amount of results has been limited.

Comment: It's very well possible that they decided @nsma_ isn't interesting enough.

Comment: Haha, don't tell my client;-)